# Rails 4 search from "home page" to other models/controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

UPDATE 4-6-2015:

Double checked here:
https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack

to make sure I had everything right, aside from a few hiccups I think I do.  I am not clear how or what automagic makes the f.submit whisk the user away to that model index with nothing in that model filled out, and the index action taking presidence (hence after doing a search takes me to the index view of the groups (what I am searching on) and shows everything from db as if the Group.all was called ignoring the search string (that I can see in the address bar) completely.

Really not sure what I am missing I am sure it something minusculey stupid on my part.

EDIT/UPDATE:  So i got most of this working, the search screen is going to that controller.  I am not sure what automagic is causing that, I thought my respond_to could trap and send back json so I could this with an ajax call and update the table that is in the main page.  THEN if they click on that table it takes them to the edit form of that particular item (i.e. the edit of the correct model).
My `visitor_controller.rb`:

```
 def index              
     @search = Group.ransack(name_cont: params[:q])
     @groups = @search.result
      respond_to do |format|
       format.html 
       format.js
     end 
end
```

Adding the routes file too:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :groups
  get 'visitors', to: 'visitors#index'
  root to: 'visitors#index'
end
```

So groups is a controller/model that I am trying to search on (one of many, will use the example in the answer to do many when I get the one just working first.)

So I am building an app, I found a "simple search" tutorial for rails 4:

http://www.stefanosioannou.com/rails-4-simple-search-form/

But I think that this assumes you to search from the view/model and all that of your controller.  I.e.
I am in the groups view, I want to search my groups all through that controller.

Really what I am doing and finding so hard to do is have a welcome page, that has three search bars.  Each bar searches a different model/view/controller.

The welcome page is called visitors and has its own controller, and view just no model.

So my visitors controller has this:

```
class VisitorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @groups = Group.search(params[:gsearch])
      respond_to do |format|
       format.html 
       format.js
     end 
  end
end
```

I was just trying to get one search bar working for my Group model, so in my Visitors index.html.erb:

```
<div class="span12">
<h3>Welcome IPA of NM</h3>
<!-- search bar here -->
 <% form_tag group_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :gsearch, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search Groups", :name => nil %>
    </p>
<% end %>
</div>
```

This fails though as it says

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"groups"} missing required keys: [:id]`

so here is my groups controller:

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController  
    before_action :set_group, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def show
    end

 private
     # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
     def set_group
       @group = Group.find(params[:id])
     end
end
```

I am sure somehow the form code in the visitors index.html.erb is working with that group_path which means it is trying to do a show but has no ID yet when just starting?  I really am lost, new to rails4 and not sure what I am missing here.  I am guessing the convention is do all things from your model/view/controller not a cross views as I am trying to do here?  So something I have to do extra to get around the convention or I am doing the whole thing wrong from the get go?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend Ransack for search queries in rails. You can view it here > https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack and you can also watch an awesome rails cast by Ryan Bates over at http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack

Ransack works across the board, you could even search all 3 models from the same form.

Using ransack, you would simply use:

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>

  # Search if the models name field contains...
  <%= f.label :name_cont %>
  <%= f.search_field :name_cont %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Then the search controller processes this into @results:

```
  def index
        @q = params[:q]

        @search = Model.search(name_cont: @q)   
        @results = @search.result
    end
```

Then you would loop through the results on your show/index page.

```
<% @results.each do |result| %>
    <%= result.name
<% end %>
```

This would show all of your results on one search page. If you wanted to search multiple models, you can either have multiple forms assigning a different instance variable for each one eg: `@q1` `@q2` `@q3` or, you could search them all from one model by using different instance variables for the search and results.eg

```
def index
    @q = params[:q]

    @firstsearch = User.search(username_cont: @q)
    @secondsearch = Post.search(title_or_description_cont: @q)

    @users = @firstsearch.result
    @posts = @secondsearch.result
end
```

Remember to add the routes =)

`get 'search', to: 'search#index'`

Comment: I will give this a spin,  I hope it plays nice with Rails4, most the railscasts I have found I am not rails-versed enough to update for rails4 and I just fail miserably at using it.

Comment: I've successfully used ransack in rails 4 a few times =) it's pretty straight forward. A lot of the time,if you get stuck, converting rails 3 to rails 4 is just a case of moving a colon and removing the hash rocket. For example `(:foo => "bar")` is now `(foo: "bar")`.

Comment: I wish I could up vote a comment too :). Thanks and marking this as answered going with ransack.  It is hard to keep calm and Gem on.

Comment: When you say add the routes, if I didn't have a search page but a Visitor page (with the search on it) would i say `get 'visitor', to: 'visitor:index'` ??  I ask cause something is missing, I keep getting a undefined method 'result' for the active record relation and that is the `result` as in `@search.result`

Comment: The search route actually sends you to /search with a query bolted on - do you want the / to be visitor?

Comment: I might.  I actually fixed the other issue, had to do Group.ransack not Group.search and get the result from that.  I know this, I want this page to go search the model, return the results in an ajax like way, and then if they click on the result they are taken to the proper controller/view show/edit area for that record in that model.  Currently what happens is I do a search and it just takes me to the Index of that controller/model im searching on after I click the "search" button (as a submit)

Comment: So I did try all this, and it does put the search string through but it does nothing with it... it seems to  goto the controller/view of the item i am searching but all items come up then.  I guess its getting the index action and I am not indeed doing the routing right?  I am editing my question and updating

Comment: Which page does it go to? Usually it would go to /search which is the index in your search controller. Then, in your search controller you would define results, from the search, for example, your search variable would be `@search = Post.search(title_cont: @q)` Then your results would be next `@posts = @search.result` then on your views/search/index page you would rum a loop on @posts which would display the results. I hope this makes sense =)

Comment: it does, I thank you a lot for the help.  I think I am confused as to what ransack is doing for me, I don't have a search controller.  I have a groups, providers and a few others, plus my visitor controller (like the home page) is where the search input is.  I would like it to (using ajax) get a search and then load it with any kinds of results it finds and displays the proper divs.  If it finds the result in groups, display that on the visitor page (where search bar is) and then if they click on a result take them to the groups editor in that controller.  I hope I made sense :)

Comment: still no dice on this?